# Cannot build wheels when trying to install Manim

Tags: python, installation, manim

I am trying to install manim on my PC. Every time I try to use

```
choco install manim
```

It says that manim is already installed!

When I try to then use pip install... it comes up with:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for manimpango, mapbox-earcut, pycairo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Any help with how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: (if you are windows user)

Install Microsoft Visual Studio Installer and download Visual Studio Build Tool in it. Then retry to see if it works.

[image: VS tools]

Comment: Why would installing Visual Studio help?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi When I use pip to download manim, I cannot build dependency because of it. So I install the build tools and it worked.

Comment: How do you know it won't work when you don't even try?